# No Output from Show Image box at Choregraphe

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I'm new in Choregraphe and programming Pepper. I tried use the function Show Image at the Choregraphe (version 2.5) and wanted to create a slide shows for my images. It works when only 1 image or 1 ShowImage Function Box, but when i connect it with a delay and 2nd ShowImage box, it just won't works and only the first image will be displayed in the Pepper's tablet and not the 2nd image. There seems like no output from the first ShowImage box to continue the sequence as the input for the delay function.

The output of the 1st Function is set as "Bang" type and nature of "onstopped"

Any can help on this?

Comment: Just a guess: is the two image file nammed the same ? if yes, then you could face a caching problem. Try using two different filenames. If not, post your code, it's harder to guess with no clue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no output because the output bang is generated when the box "stops", meaning the image is not being shown anymore. That doesnt happen unless you manually stop it.

Try linking a first wait box to the start of th behaviour so it starts ticking as soon as it starts and then use the output bang from this wait box to trigger the second image and a new wait box which will trigger a third image and wait box and so on.

There are several more elegant ways to do this with events, but if you want to keep it simple, the above will work.

EDIT: I'll add an image for reference
[image: Example]